# Encrypt works, but not decrypt in openpgp.js

Tags: javascript, pgp, openpgp.js

I am trying to decrypt and encrypt strings with openpgp.js.

Encryption works fine, but I can't decrypt. I really can't get it to work.

Here is a working example of the encryption: https://jsfiddle.net/d4vL8ueh/1/

```
var message = "secret message";
const encryptMessage  = async() => {
  if(window.crypto.getRandomValues){
    if(message != ""){
      const publicKeyString = document.getElementById("pubkey").innerHTML;

      var options = {
        message: openpgp.message.fromText(message),
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(publicKeyString)).keys
      };


openpgp.encrypt(options).then(ciphertext => {
        alert(ciphertext.data);

    })



    }
  }
  else{
    window.alert("This browser does not support basic cryptography!");
  }
}

encryptMessage();
```

But the decryption doesn't work at all: https://jsfiddle.net/pceswg0t/2/

```
const decryptMessage  = async() => {
  encrypted = document.getElementById("encrypted").innerHTML;
  if(window.crypto.getRandomValues){
    if(encrypted != ""){
      const privateKeyString =  document.getElementById("privkey").innerHTML;

      var options = {
        message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(message),
        privateKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privateKeyString)).keys,
        passphrase: "dfgjk23jkfdklfsdds232334fddf"
      };


openpgp.decrypt(options).then(plaintext => {
        decrypted = plaintext.data
        alert(decrypted);
    })



   }
  }
  else{
    window.alert("This browser does not support basic cryptography!");
  }
}
decryptMessage();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

Firstly, a non-existent `message` variable is being passed into `readArmored` when setting `options.message`. This should be using the `encrypted` variable instead:

```
message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),
```

Secondly, the private key is encrypted, so it needs to be decrypted before it can be used. This can be done by calling `decrypt()` on the key before it is used:

```
var privateKeys = await openpgp.key.readArmored(privateKeyString);
privateKeys.keys[0].decrypt("dfgjk23jkfdklfsdds232334fddf")

var options = {
    message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),
    privateKeys: privateKeys.keys
};
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfkqbsoz/